# Java : what is the most effective connection pool?

Tags: java, hibernate, deployment, connection-pooling

I am already familiar with 3 different popular connection pools (already read the advantages and disadvantages from existing questions and home sites):

C3P0, DBCP, BoneCP.

1. Are their any new connection pools available that may supply better performance.
2. Which one of the 3 is the **most popular in use at the industry** - i will be happy to read answers like: we are using X connection pool in our deployment project, we strongly advice you to use it as opposed to ... , Why?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For our projects we use BoneCP:

http://jolbox.com/

which has much better performance than C3P0 and Apache's DBCP.

Comment: Thanks, looks promising.